# Find and remove numbers from given number

Tags: c++

For example, user enters digit `542035`. The application must, cut all `5`s and `0`s from given digit and print `423`. Can't figure out, simple way to write something like "find and remove" all 0s and 5s from digit? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can convert it to a string and go from there.

Comment: Since you've said the user enters the number, it has to come in as a string already.  Have a look at `std::string`, and `std::remove_if`.  Is this homework?

Answer (score 5):

Convert the number to a string, perform a replace (replacing the digits with ""), display the result.

Comment: can you write some example code?

Comment: @epic_syntax: Yes, I could.  Do you not know how to convert a number to a string and perform a replace in C?  They are pretty basic concepts and there exists a ton of examples on the internet already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using C++11.

**Note:** If this is a homework question, this is likely *not* the answer the teacher is looking for, though it is idiomatic.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s("542035");

   std::cout << "Input: " << s << "\n";

   auto new_end = std::remove_if(
      s.begin(),
      s.end(),
      [] (const char c) -> bool
   {
      switch(c)
      {
      case '5':
      case '0':
         return true;
      default:
         return false;
      }
   });

   s.assign(s.begin(), new_end);

   std::cout << "Result: " << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I would think trice before submitting this as my homework answer

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me for this problem. I'm not sure if its the best solution though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userinput;

cin >> userinput;

string s;

stringstream out;

out << userinput;

s = out.str();

cout << s << " " << userinput << endl;

vector<char> editted;

string::iterator it;

for (it = s.begin() ; it < s.end(); it++ )
{
if ((*it) == '5' || (*it) == '0')
{}
else 
editted.push_back((*it));
}

for (int i = 0; i <editted.size(); i++)
{
cout << editted[i] << endl;
} 

return 0;
}
```